# Query Product categories what have a custom field

Tags: customization, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Im trying to build a page template on wordpress that will show a list a categories that have a custom field checked.

So the taxonomy is just the default woocommerce taxonomy `product_cat` I then have a custom field to the product_cat taxonomy which is a check box called `collectable`

My set up is
Main Category

- Child
- Child
- Child
- Child

So for example 2 children categories have the tick box `collectable`  which is set to add the value of 1 into the datbase

So I am doing a page where it will show all categories with the collectable checked.

```
$args = array(
    'post-type' => 'product',
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => 0
  );
  $c = get_categories($args);
  $c_keep = array();
  foreach($c as  $cat){
 if (get_field('collectable', 'category_'.$cat->term_id)) {
      $c_keep[] = $cat;
    }  
  }
  
  foreach($c_keep as $cat){
    echo $cat->name;
  }
```

But I am getting nothing at all returned.

I even put a

```
print_r( $args );
```

But I am still coming up with a blank (Header and footer Loads and the text above the query)

Can anyone help please

****** EDIT *****

Did as suggest to run a meta query

```
<?php

$terms = get_terms( 
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'meta_key' => 'collectable',
            'meta_value' => '1',
    )
    );
$terms = get_terms( $args ); 

  foreach($terms as $cat){ ?>
<?php echo $cat->name; ?> <BR>

<?php
}
print_r( $terms );
?>
```

This just bought back all categories whether they have the mata_value or not

Comment: You should use a meta query to things like this.

Comment: How that would work? Because the page needs to show sub categories with "collectable" checked, not a list of products.

Comment: @user1348927 Checkout the docs and example of [WP_Term_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/)

Comment: Did as suggested, It brought back all categories. (It should be bringing back 3 currently and it returned all 65 categories.)

Comment: `get_field` is an ACF function, you want `get_term_meta` for a terms meta fields, and `get_post_meta` for a posts meta fields. It's unclear though how you've added the `collectable` field, and what you've added it to

Answer (score 0):

The meta is within the taxonomy (so I have the standard, category name, slug, description etc and then I added a collectable tickbox to the category itself not the post/product)

I solved this by Running a query for all sub categories and then I put an if statement in so it shows only categories with the collectable box ticked.

(used toolset for the custom field in the end)

```
$parent_id = 16;
$args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0, 
        'parent' => $parent_id,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $subcategories = get_categories($args);
   );
   foreach ($subcategories as $category) {
    
    $st_var = $category->to_array();
    $thumbnail_id =  types_render_termmeta("collectable",array("term_id" =>$st_var['term_id']));   
    if ( $thumbnail_id ) {

          /// Put my html here, category name, image, link etc

    }
}
```